# How re-detect an USB Flash Memory by software?

Tags: windows, flash, usb

After selecting "Safe Remove" option in windows system tray, is there any way that I can re-detect my Flash by a code, without plug it out and again inserting it to the computer USB port?

Answer (score 7):

You can look at re-scanning the system for devices.  Test this with Microsoft's [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) tool (this demonstrates SetupAPI and CfgMgr32 functionality).  The source code for the tool is available in the [Windows DDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/ddk/default.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

The program "USB Safely Remove" do that and more. But is shareware.